# Google Cloud SDK update cause error for bq

Tags: google-bigquery, gcloud

After updating Google Cloud SDK 189.0.0, previously fine command `bq query --nouse_legacy_sql " ... "` now error as follow:

`$ python --version
Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda, Inc.
$ bq version
This is BigQuery CLI 2.0.29
$ bq query --nouse_legacy_sql "SELECT country, model, iid, version, count(*) as n, max(t) AS t FROM an6.sm GROUP BY country, model, iid, version ORDER BY t DESC LIMIT 10 "
bq.py should not be invoked. Use bq command instead.
$`

Restoring previous version work again.

```
$ gcloud components restore
Your Cloud SDK installation will be restored to its previous state.

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

Restoring backup...

Performing post processing steps...done.
Restoration done!

$ bq query --nouse_legacy_sql "SELECT country, model, iid, version, count(*) as n, max(t) AS t FROM an6.sm GROUP BY country, model, iid, version ORDER BY t DESC LIMIT 10 "
Waiting on bqjob_r13976b38780fa35_00000161ab5076fe_1 ... (1s) Current 
status: DONE
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Upgraded to 189.0.0 and it works fine. What Python version are using?

Comment: I have the exact same error. The place where this broke was on a VM I setup a long time ago, running on Compute Engine. The bq program I am calling comes from /usr/local/bin/bq, a symlink to /usr/local/share/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bq - not sure this is related.

Comment: To add more about my previous comment, here is a list of versions: https://gist.github.com/ronoaldo/14dbb69184594fc0e59771f698b95a76

Comment: If you delete the ~/.bigqueryrc and the associated legacy bigquery credential it also fails.

Comment: I got the same error after upgrading...  running "restore" fixed the problem.  I noticed, also, that the 'bq' in bin/ has not changed since September.

Comment: I have the same problem with the latest update to the tools (gcloud 189.0.0, bq 2.0.29) running Python 2.7.10.

Comment: I just updated again to 191.0.0 and still had the same problem -- then followed the suggestions below to resolve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try revoking and initializing your gcloud credentials:

```
gcloud auth revoke <credentials you're using>
gcloud auth login
```

or replace 'login' with the command you used to authenticate, if it was different.

Comment: `gcloud auth init` doesn't appear to be a valid command. Do you mean `gcloud auth login` or `gcloud auth application-default login`? I tried this and it cleared up the OP problem but led to "Cannot access ~/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/XXXXX/singlestore_bq.json: No such file or directory". In any case, these seems like a pretty big change to resolve this issue.

Comment: That "singlestore_bq.json" error message seems to go away after the first time it runs, so I think it cleans itself up.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer. Yes, I meant 'login'. Glad it worked.

Comment: I wasn't sure which "credentials" to revoke, so I just moved ~/.config/gcloud to a new location (as backup) and then ran gcloud auth login, and then gcloud config set project, and that seemed to clear things up.

Answer (score 1):

If your previous state was a good one, you can revert the upgrade to 189.0.0 by executing:

```
gcloud components restore
```

Doing this reverted my SDK back to 172.0.1 and bq to 2.0.26 both which I could execute from the VM again.

```
$ bq query "SELECT COUNT(word) FROM [bigquery-public-data:samples.shakespeare] LIMIT 1000" 
Waiting on bqjob_r1ac52f8ef09f41c2_00000161a981cfac_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE   
+--------+
|  f0_   |
+--------+
| 164656 |
+--------+
```